# publish link of APK android

Tags: android, apk

I want to publish a link of my android application on some hosting (not to publish in google play).

I see two files with extension.apk
first one located in `app >> release >> app-release.apk`
and

second one located in `app >> build >> outputs >> APK >> debug > app-debug.apk`

I am trying to publish the first one but when I tried to install it failed
the second one was successfully installed but it takes the code before updating.

I mean that install code with the last update from two days ago.
where `app-debug.apk` is immediately updated when I change anything in my code.
why this problem appears and how to solve it?

In addition, when I run my application it displays to me this runtime errors in `logcat`, but all function work fine.
I do not know if this error related to my problem.

---

```
12420-12420/com.example.lenovo.tactic E/Zygote: v2
12420-12420/com.example.lenovo.tactic E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
12420-12420/com.example.lenovo.tactic E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12420-12420/com.example.lenovo.tactic E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
12420-12420/com.example.lenovo.tactic E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@64340d8
12420-12420/com.example.lenovo.tactic E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@7749c31
12420-12420/com.example.lenovo.tactic E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@7749c31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some major difference in both the apk's

> one located in app >> build >> outputs >> APK >> debug > app-debug.apk

1. This is your debug apk file which gets updated every time you perform a full install of your app from Android studio (not instant run).
2. For debug builds the apk will be signed with the default debug signing keys with debug flag enabled.
3. A debug build is actually a fully self-contained apk version which is even deployable in a production environment with the limitation of lacking some code compression/optimization/shrinking plus developer authentication.

> one located in app >> release >> app-release.apk

1. This is your Release apk and it gets updated only when you generate `signed-apk` from Android studio.
2. For release builds you will have to explicitly specify the keys to sign with and the debug flag will be turned off so that it cannot be debugged.
3. Proguard (to obfuscate code)can be turned on for release builds. (also for debug builds but not advised). This step needs to be done explicitly and is false by default.

So if you are Publishing your app somewhere it is advised to publish signed/release apk.

> I am trying to publish the first one but when I tried to install it failed.

Perform a clean build and enter credentials correctly(password and .jks file).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One is the release apk, one is the debug.  When you just hit the run button, you build the debug version.  When you tell it to build a release version, it builds the release version (and generally signs it with your release key).  You typically only want to publish the release version, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: How can I get the last version of app-release.apk?